# Spring data mongodb reactive: use spring.data.mongodb.uri or implement AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration.getDatabaseName

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm reading on several sites, I need to configure something like that in order to get access to mongodb.

```java
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
public class MongoReactiveApplication
  extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "<database>";
    }
}
```

I'm using:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://<user>:<password>@<rs1>:<port>,<rs2>:<port>,<rs3>:<port>/<database>
```

As you can see, I'm using `spring.data.mongodb.uri` property in order to set uri. Inside this value there is the `<database>`.

Why should I need to implement `AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration.getDatabaseName` once again programatically?

Comment: Are you sing Spring Boot? If you're using Spring Boot then you don't have to extend the `AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration`, and let autoconfigure take care of bootstrapping the stuff for you, i.e. just put @EnableReactiveMongoRepositories somewhere to be found and that's it.
If however, you're using Spring Data MongoDB in standalone, then you need the config.